# convert html string to morionette object python

Tags: python

i am using Mariontte client (firefox)

```
client.navigate('https://www.example.com')
html = client.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")
login = html.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'login button')
if login:
    login.click()
```

as you see i want to automate some actions that need to get website pagesource after running javascripts as Marionette object.
then, i use rendered-html code to do somethings like press button and etc. but at first i need to convert html to marionette object

this line return error:

```
login = html.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'login button')
```

because html is not a Marionette object. it is an unicode object!!!

thanks

Comment: login = client.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'login button')

Comment: @Rish dear, "login button" is not in pagesource that we see in viewpagesource at firefox... i need the source after rendering by javascript

Comment: https://marionette-client.readthedocs.io/en/master/advanced/stale.html#explicit-waiting-and-expected-conditions

Comment: @Rish thanks, i do that and now get this error:

NoSuchElementException: Web element reference not seen before: 8d855479-07f1-4dfe-84b2-fa28f7b97f64